# remove line <br> in ruby string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my form, I have a textarea field where user can enter data and press 'Enter' to put line breaks and continue entering data.

When I am retrieving data from the database, I need to remove all line breaks and store that data in a a JavaScript array.

In the example below, I am retrieving a note (which contains several line breaks `<br/>`) and storing in in an array called 'exp_from_db'

```
exp_from_db[1]= '<%= note.NOTE_VALUE %>';
```

My question is how do I remove those line breaks in `<%= note.NOTE_VALUE %>` before storing it in the javascript array.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string `<br/>` and variations of it *(`<br>`, `<br />`, `<br    >`)* are all you want to remove, `gsub` is one way

```
note.NOTE_VALUE.gsub(/<br\s*\/?>/, '')
```

If you *always* want to strip this, you can modify the getter for `NOTE_VALUE` in the ActiveRecord class

```
def NOTE_VALUE
  read_attribute("NOTE_VALUE").gsub(/<br(\s*\/)?>/, '')
end
```

Comment: What about `<br      >`? Look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated mine. Yours is wrong too though as it allows `<br /////>`.

Comment: I can't write here in comments br and three spaces after that :)
You are right I will edit it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
note.NOTE_VALUE.gsub(/\<br\s*\/?\>/, "")
```

will remove all occurrences: `<br />`, `<br/>` or `<br>`.

Try this example in irb:

```
puts "text<br /> some text <br>another text<br/>".gsub(/\<br\s*\/?\>/, "")
```

Comment: I agree with you. The slash is optional as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub

You could do something like:

```
parsed_string = exp_from_db[1].gsub(/<br\/>/, '')
```

This should replace any instances of your br tag with a blank string, thus removing them.

Comment: As in my suggestion, you could add `\s*` right after `br` to take into account possible multiple spaces/tabs/newlines before the self-closing of the tag.

Comment: And you could add `\/*` instead of `\/` because of `<br>` where `/` isn't present.

Comment: Yep, did that in my suggestion above, thanks. For a moment I forgot what a horrific soup of HTML tags one can find in the open.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Rails, you have two choices:

- If you are **certain** your DB value doesn't contain other HTML tags (or it does, but you don't care if they are wiped), you can simply do this: `strip_tags(note.NOTE_VALUE)`, but you have to be mindful that this would wipe any HTML tags in your string, not only `<br/>` occurences.
- Or, you can simply use gsub to get rid of these: `note.NOTE_VALUE.gsub(/<br\s*\/?>/, '')`. *Note that this regex takes into account possible spaces/newlines/tabs before the self-closing of the `br` tag.*